# Facing Issues in WinForm Integration with my Existing Azure Bot Using Directline API

Tags: c#, winforms, botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework

I have created a bot using Bot Framework SDK (C#, .Net). I have published it in Azure. It is working fine in WebChat as well as in Teams channel. Now I want to create one Winform and trying to connect the Winform UI to my bot using Directline Api.

This is my code :

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

```
    private static string directLineSecret = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DirectLineSecret"];

    private static string botId = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BotId"];

    private static string fromUser = "User";
    private static string id = "default-user";

    private Conversation conversation;
    DirectLineClient directLineClient = null;
    

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitClientAsync();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    private async Task InitClientAsync()
    {
        directLineClient = new DirectLineClient($"{directLineSecret}");
        directLineClient.BaseUri = new Uri($"https://directline.botframework.com/");

        //directLineClient = new DirectLineClient(directLineSecret);
        conversation = await directLineClient.Conversations.StartConversationAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

            new System.Threading.Thread(async () => await ReadBotMessageAsync(directLineClient, conversation.ConversationId)).Start();
        
    }

    private async Task ReadBotMessageAsync(DirectLineClient client, string conversationId)
    {
        string watermark = null;

        while(true)
        {
            var activitySet = await client.Conversations.GetActivitiesAsync(conversationId, watermark);
            watermark = activitySet?.Watermark;

            var activities = from x in activitySet.Activities where x.From.Id == botId select x;

            foreach(Activity activity in activities)
            {
                if(activity.Text != null)
                {
                    string message = activity.Text;
                    if(InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                        {
                            textBox.AppendText("Bot : " + message + "\r\n");
                        }));
                    }
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async void btn_Send_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string input = txt_Send.Text;
        txt_Send.Clear();
        if(input.Length>0)
        {
            Activity userMessage = new Activity
            {
                From = new ChannelAccount(id, fromUser),
                Text = input,
                Type = ActivityTypes.Message,
                TextFormat = "plain"
            };
            textBox.AppendText("You : " + input + "\r\n");
            await directLineClient.Conversations.PostActivityAsync(this.conversation.ConversationId, userMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

But when I execute the program it is stopping due to Null reference exception when it is trying to get conversation as well as conversation Id.

you can check the [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eu0kT.png) here.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing here?
Any help will be appreciated.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the directline secret key. I regenerate a new key and used it. Now that is starting the conversation and I am able to see conversation Id.

But after that I was getting status code 429 error. That is basically Multiple thread issue. It is trying to create multiple threads at the same time.
Then I recreate the whole project with .Net Framework version 4.6.2 (Previously using 4.7). Now that issue also got resolved. Project is working fine.